# TreeMap in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeMap;
public class Manager {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

          TreeMap tmap1 = new TreeMap(new C.D());
          tmap1.put(new C(9, 1), 9);
          tmap1.put(new C(0, 10), 19);
          tmap1.put(new C(1, 8), 92);
          tmap1.put(new C(8, 0), 91);
          tmap1.put(new C(5, 4), 39);
          tmap1.put(new C(5,4), 73);//this line

          System.out.println(tmap1);
        }
}

  class C {
      int i, j;

         C(int i, int j) {
             this.i = i;
             this.j = j;
           }

        public String toString() {
           return "(i=" + i + ",j=" + j + ")";
         }

       static class D implements Comparator {
             public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
               return ((C)obj1).i - ((C)obj2).i;
             }
      }

  }
```

//As we know TreeMap sorts based on the key and here I am passing it a comparator and its sorting based on variable i.When I tried to enter new entry in treemap1 as I mentioned it in comment as `//this line`, its adding this new entry while deleting previous same entry. Well Class C does not override hashcode() and equals() method so the new entry is completedly different from it previous entry as they have different hashcode() based on Object class, so both entries should retain in map but only new one is added and previous one deleted.

Comment: A TreeMap cannot contain duplicate keys. In your case check what your comparator returns.

Comment: I think his question is how JVM knows it is duplicate.

Comment: TreeMap doesn't use hashCode(). It uses Comparator, that you passed into constructor.

Comment: @Ivan Babanin, I know that but entering key values uses it!

Comment: @Aamir where they use hashCode?

Comment: @Ivan because to check whether two keys aren't duplicated

Comment: @Aamir, nope, Comparator is used to check duplication: if compare(...) method returns 0, that means that keys are equal.

Comment: @Ivan yes I got it , it use Comparator's return value to see it two key values are duplicated or not,  thanks for clearing the doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of line

```
tmap1.put(new C(5,4), 73);
```

your comparator returns 0 so it is duplicate for JVM and it overrides it.

Put one debug statement like below and re-run your program you will understand the fact..

```
     public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
       System.out.println("in compare difference is : "+ (((C)obj1).i - ((C)obj2).i));
       return ((C)obj1).i - ((C)obj2).i;
     }
```

you will get below output..see the zero(0) at last

```
in compare : -9
in compare : -8
in compare : 1
in compare : 7
in compare : -1
in compare : 4
in compare : -4
in compare : -3
in compare : 4
in compare : -3
in compare : 0
```

Comment: is it right to say that on entering duplicate value like above in the program comparator returns same value and it becomes duplicate for treeset so that is why only one is entered.

Comment: Yes Amir..You can write appropriate logic to make them meaning fully duplicate. e.g. if object one's i+j and object two's i+j is same, consider it duplicate.. likewise

Answer (score 1):

In your case the problem is because if you use `TreeMap` and provide `Comparator` you should also provide correct `equals` method. It's in JavaDoc of TreeMap:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map, and whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, must be consistent with equals if this sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface

Your equals method is inherited from Object and it's not consistent with your Comparator.

Have a loot at `TreeMap` `put` method and compare it with `HashMap` `put` method. TreeMap's version use `compareTo` method only instead of `equals` like in HashMap's put.

Btw you shouldn't use raw types since Java 1.5